# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 6000, 19, 1), found shape=(None, 19)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am writing a code for seizure detection using EEG signals. The information from eeg signal is stored hdf file which was accessed in an data_arr of size(20, 11751680) and i transposed it to (11751680, 20) where column 1 is patient id, 18 columns are for 18 different channels and last column is the label for seizure(0) and non seizure(1).

```
#pre processing 
eeg_data = data_arr[:, :19]
labels = data_arr[:, -1:]
X_train, X_temp, y_train, y_temp = train_test_split(eeg_data, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_temp, y_temp, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)

# Define the CNN model
model = Sequential()
# Temporal Convolution Layer
model.add(Conv2D(25, (10, 1), input_shape=(6000, 19, 1), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 1)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
# Spatial Convolution Layer
model.add(Conv2D(25, (1, 18), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 1)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(Conv2D(50, (10, 1), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 1)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(Conv2D(100, (10, 1), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 1)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(Conv2D(200, (10, 1), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 1)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3,1)))
# Flatten the output
model.add(Flatten())

# Linear Classifier with Softmax Activation
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=10, batch_size=6000)

# Evaluate the model
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_acc}")
```

Here i want my input to be of size 6000X19 and the model.fit is showing the above error.
Can someone please provide the solution for the same

Comment: The input shape should not contain the samples dimensions (i.e. the 60000).

Comment: To add to Dr. Snoopy's comment, your input shape is `(19,)`, but the model expects `(19, 1)`. So you either expand the last dimension of your data, or you can use the `1D` equivalent for `Conv` and `Pool` and adjust the `input_shape` parameter. Also, I'm not sure you want the patient ID column in your input data.

Comment: where is the errpr message?